# Port forwarding through OpenVPN server

Tags: centos, openvpn, forwarding, csf

Here's my scenario:

1. Remote OpenVPN server v2.3.2, 1 public IP, CentOS 6.4, 2.6.32-042stab079.6
2. Tunnelblick (OpenVPN client)

What I want to do is route all the client traffic through the VPN - and I accomplished that. I'm however experiencing problems in port forwarding clients port through the VPN.

e.g. I need port 5780 for hosting a game match on the client, but I'm behind the VPN, therefore the VPN gets the packets. I'd like the VPN to forward every packet on port 5780 to my client IP address.

How can I do so?
Please note that the remote server runs CSF+LFD.

Comment: "I'm however experiencing problems in port forwarding clients port through the VPN."  What have you tried here?  What config settings?  Where have they failed?  What's in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NAT the packets to your client via iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5780 -i $external_Interface -j DNAT --to-destination $VPN_client_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $vpn_Interface -j MASQUERADE
```

Update: You will also need a FORWARD rule in place if your FORWARD policy is set to DROP. As you can see [here](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png), the FORWARD takes place between the PREROUTING and POSTROUTING, therefore the DNAT is already done. This should work:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i $external_Interface -d $VPN_client_IP --dport $port -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I added the following rules:

`sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 51413 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 51413 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.6
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
` but the packets don't seem to get forwarded looking at tcpdump.

Comment: Is IP forwarding enabled? Check `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. As you're running CSF+LFD , there are probably a lot more rules, you should check your whole iptables configuration.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's in sysctl.conf as well

Comment: Check your iptables config. What else is in there?

Comment: As iptables -L states: http://sprunge.us/jjFP

Comment: And `iptables -t nat -L` ? I'd also suggest to completely turn off the firewall for testing and only establish the NAT rules to see if it works.

Comment: Nat rules: http://sprunge.us/dGRM I'd prefer not to turn off the firewall unless really needed for testing

Comment: Any idea by looking at the nat rules? I tried looking at csf options as well but I don't seem to find anything related.

Comment: the nat rules seem ok, but I'd still suggest to temporarily disable the firewall completely for debugging.

Comment: I completely disabled the firewall and tried, but it still doesn't work. tcpdump lets me see the packet arriving to the remote IP, but no packet gets then sent to the local IP, as if no forwarding had been set.

Comment: I found something. Apparently there needs to be a FORWARD rule, 'cause with default policy ACCEPT for the FORWARD chain it works. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updates my answer.

Comment: There's no nat table in the FORWARD chain, so I had to take out the -t parameter. Anyway, this solved it. I basically had previously added a ACCEPT rule for the -s way but not for the -d (in fact, the packet simply didn't get forward at all). Thank you for your help!

Comment: oops, the nat is caused by copy&paste, of course it doesn't belong there ;)